# How to use $index in interpolate

Tags: angularjs

I have loop:

`<div ng-repeat="item in items">
{{ foo }}
</div>`

I want to use `$index` to change scope name, like this:
`{{ foo + $index }}` - i want foo0.

This example dosen't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> String should be in `quote`(double or single)

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
{{"foo" + $index}}
</div>
```

Check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4sv32u3w/)

> EDIT : To show variable value with $index

```
    <div ng-repeat="line in lines">
         {{name}} - {{  $index}}
    </div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/halirgb/Lvc0u55v/ This display a name. I want to display a value of 'foo0' etc.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4sv32u3w/1/ check this. I have updated the jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry, i pasted bad link. Can you check this: https://jsfiddle.net/4sv32u3w/2/ ? I want to display 'Value of foo0',  'Value of foo1' etc.

Comment: try this link : https://jsfiddle.net/j2m3afh0/ , I have changed the way you were accessing

Answer (score 1):

you can display the value of foo0 , foo1 etc by using a function

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
{{testFunc('foo',$index)}}
<div>
```

return the value of the scope variable.

```
$scope.testFunc= function(fieldName,index){

return $scope[fieldName+index];
}
```

Check -- http://jsfiddle.net/696d98df/

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ 'foo' + $index }}
```

Here's what you need to do

As per your request, Value of foo1 etc. can be displayed like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/jonva/hLj9jm4g/

```
Value of {{ 'foo' + $index }}
```

The better way of doing this would be

```
$scope.foos = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3'] 
//and reference it as 

Value of {{ foos[ $index ]}}
```

Comment: jsfiddle.net/4sv32u3w/2 This display a name.  I want to display 'Value of foo0', 'Value of foo1' etc.

Comment: This is only example, i want to display all from '$scope.foo0'

Comment: Why not put it in an array like `$scope.foos = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3']` and reference it as `Value of {{ foos[ $index ]}}`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
{{"foo" + $index}}
</div>
```

I think, this is more useful